# How to check if an object contains another object?

Tags: javascript

```
var person = {
       "name" : "Bronn",
       "description" : {
          "occupation" : "guardian knight",
          "age" : 52
       }
    }

for(var key in person){
   if(person[key] == /*contains json object */){
      //do something
   }
}
```

I want to loop this person and check if its value contains single data or another object.

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: `array` is not defined anywhere. How exactly should we qualify "single data" in that regard?

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [typeof()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to get reuired result and using [Array's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) iterator.

**Update :**

You use [`Object.prototype.toString.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), to get type of value. It will return the value like below

```js
const getTypeOfValue = (value) => Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();

console.log('If value is Number then return type is :-', getTypeOfValue(1));

console.log('If value is String then return type is :-', getTypeOfValue('test'));

console.log('If value is Object then return type is :-', getTypeOfValue({key:'value'}));

console.log('If value is Array then return type is :-', getTypeOfValue([{key:'value'}]));

console.log('If value is NULL then return type is :-', getTypeOfValue(null));

console.log('If value is Undefined then return type is :-', getTypeOfValue());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**Working Demo**

```js
var person = {"name": "Bronn","description": {"occupation": "guardian knight","age": 52}},
  keys = Object.keys(person);

const getType = (value) => Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();

//ES5
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  if (getType(person[key]) === 'object') {
    console.log('Find using ES5',person[key]);
  }
});

//ES6 syntax
keys.forEach(key => {
  if (getType(person[key]) === 'object') {
    console.log('Find using ES6', person[key]);
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `typeof` will give an `object`, even if it is an array. What if you don't want arrays ?

Comment: @ShashankAC Have updated the answer, you can find another way to check type of the value.

Answer (score 2):

Its just normal object not JSON.And [filter](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQh-XM-aPWAhVLPI8KHaPFAQAQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHTybPLK3GeAl_0DVx-FLbAD2mWtw) the [object values](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwih28DA-aPWAhVEpI8KHbIRBmgQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_objects%2FObject%2Fvalues&usg=AFQjCNE5UlL1cEh99fUgeunohGICKbz8Ew) with `typeof() == object` .The length of the filtered array shown object is present or not

```js
var person = {
       "name" : "Bronn",
       "description" : {
          "occupation" : "guardian knight",
          "age" : 52
       }
    }
console.log('its contains any object=',Object.values(person).filter(a=> typeof(a) == 'object').length > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply check it's constructor like below

```
for(var key in person){
   if(person[key].constructor == Object){
     //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check with `typeof` for `object`, but you need to check the value as well, because `null` is an object and a value.

```js
var person = { foo: null, name: "Bronn", description: { occupation: "guardian knight", age: 52 } },
    keysOfObjects = Object.keys(person).filter(key => typeof person[key] == 'object'),
    wantedKeys = Object.keys(person).filter(key => person[key] && typeof person[key] == 'object');

console.log(keysOfObjects);
console.log(wantedKeys);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```