# Check if object is included in another object

Tags: javascript

```
let a = { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }

let b = {last: "Capulet" }
```

How do I check if 'a' contains 'b'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an object contains another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211122/how-to-check-if-an-object-contains-another-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object Comparing: check if an object contains the whole other object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045652/object-comparing-check-if-an-object-contains-the-whole-other-object)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways to obtain what you desire

1st-> like Jack Bashford has done with his answer

2nd -> use rest operators to make a new object and compare object with itself

```
let a = { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }

let b = {last: "Capulet" }
let combinedObj = {...a, ...b}
```

if `a` contains `b` in it, the `combinedObj` will be equal to `a`. Then you can use any object comparison module to check if `combinedObj` and `a` are equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```js
let a = { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet", age: 20 }
let b = { last: "Capulet", first:"Tybalt" }
var result = false ;

function getLength(obj) {
  var len = 0 ;
  for( key in obj ) 
    len++ ;
  return len ;
}

if ( getLength(a) >= getLength(b) ) {
  for ( key in b ) {
    if (b[key] !== a[key] ) {
      result = false ;
      break ;
    }
    result = true ;
  }
}

console.log( result ) ;
```

Comment: Why not JSON.stringify for converting to string?

Comment: This fails when the property order isn't the same. For example if `b`  is `{last: "Capulet", first: "Tybalt" }`

Comment: Hmm…interesting. Maybe if you have some sort of separator between key and value that will never show up. Because otherwise you have edge cases like `let b = { lastC: "apulet", first:"Tybalt" }` which pass.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each property in the smaller object, then if there are any that don't match, return `false`. Otherwise, return `true`:

```
let a = { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" };

let b = {last: "Capulet" };

function bigObjContainsSmallObj(big, small) {
    for (var prop in small) {
        if (small[prop] != big[prop]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Demonstration:

```js
let a = {
  first: "Tybalt",
  last: "Capulet"
};

let b = {
  last: "Capulet"
};

let c = {
  first: "Romeo"
}

function bigObjContainsSmallObj(big, small) {
    for (var prop in small) {
        if (small[prop] != big[prop]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(bigObjContainsSmallObj(a, b));
console.log(bigObjContainsSmallObj(a, c));
```

Comment: `small[prop] != big[prop]` this may not work if the values are object (array, json).

Comment: Since you’re returning from inside the loop, this won’t work if small object has more than 1 prop.

Comment: @DerekNguyen it will only return if the values aren't equal which means the properties don't match. If a property doesn't match there's no reason to continue looping.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ah true, my bad Jack, I was thinking of looking for common properties, which is not what OP's question about

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
function checkObj(obj, obj2, property){
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty( property ) ) {
        console.log('Yes. It has the '+ property);
        if(obj[property] === obj2[property]){
            console.log('And the values are both '+ obj2[property]);
        }
    }
}

checkObj(a, b, 'last');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each keys of `b` object and check if its value is equal to value of that key in `a` object.

```js
let a = { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" },
    b = { last: "Capulet" },
    c = { here: 'property'},
    isObjectPresent = (a, b) => {
      return Object.keys(b).every(k => k in a && a[k] === b[k]); 
    }
console.log(isObjectPresent(a,b));
console.log(isObjectPresent(a,c))
```